# How do I store the value of a javascript variable (without a server) externally?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, variables

Lets say I am asking users (on my local machine) to input their email address to sign up for a raffle.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head><title>Raffle</title></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var email;
        function foo(){
            email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
            alert(email);
        }
</script>
<body>
<input id="Email" name="Email" type="email">
<input type="Submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="foo();">
</body>
```

## Fiddle

When the user hits submit, the email address pops up in front of them. Is there any way to simultaneously store the variable `email` in an external file (`.php`, `.txt` etc.)

Comment: not sure what u r asking, but may be it will do: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: No, JavaScript code in a browser can't create or write to files on the file system. You can, however, use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

Comment: Not sure about the technology you're trying to use... Are you wanting to store by using JS or can you use PHP? Seems like you could do a write using php to a file anywhere you want in the file system.

Comment: Well, aren't cookies ultimately stored on the filesystem?

Comment: @KimGysen JS code can _indirectly_ cause files to be created or modified. It does not, however have control over the names of the files that are created or where they are created, and it can only interact with this data in certain ways.

Comment: Ok. I don't understand the question entirely, not sure what's the intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a server, the only persistence you're going to get from JavaScript is through cookies, local storage, or one of the client-side DB methods. (There are ways to write data to files but they are often more hassle than they're worth for such simple cases).

Simplest is [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API). This will keep a comma-separated string of all emails users have entered:

```
if (!localStorage.emails)
    localStorage.emails = email;
else
    localStorage.emails += ',' + email;
```

And then at subsequent page visits, you can retrieve the emails that users entered through the `localStorage.emails` variable.

Comment: @Godisgood: Understood, though the OP said "without a server".

Comment: @Godisgood: Fair enough. I've edited my answer to include a warning.

Comment: @Godisgood how is doing a raffle impossible without a server if all the users are entering their email on one computer? OP could store all the emails in localStorage then write another function to pull out a random email for when they're doing the draw.

Comment: The people will be using the one machine, localstorage is 100% fine. I do it for quick and dirty sign ups for meetings.

Comment: Well, @DavidSherret, that assumes that they will all be on a single machine.

Comment: @Godisgood _"Lets say I am asking users __(on my local machine)__ to input their email address to sign up for a raffle._

Comment: Yes, you all are right.  I missed that.  +1 @DavidSherret :)

Answer (score 1):

in your code you have make minor changes as i understand it

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head><title>Raffle</title></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var email;
    function foo(){
        email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
        /* this function stored your email variable to another php page as a variable name php_email */
        $.post('anyphppagename.php',php_email:email,function(){
        });
        alert(email);
    }
</script>
<body>
<input id="Email" name="Email" type="email">
<input type="Submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="foo();">
</body>
```

in another way you can show this value as to the user in your jquery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var email;
function foo(){
email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
alert(email);
$("#getemail").html(email);
$("#getemail").css("display","block");
}
</script>

<body>
<span id="getemail" style="display:none;"></span>
<input id="Email" name="Email" type="email">
<input type="Submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="foo();">
</body>




hopefully it may help you
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can use `localStorage` to persist values *in a single browser*.

If you want to store a list of e-mail addresses, your best bet is to store them as an array, and serialize that into localstorage

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head><title>Raffle</title></head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function storeEmail(email) {
            var addressesSerialized = localStorage.emails || "[]";
            var addresses = JSON.parse(addressesSerialized);

            addresses.push(email);
            localStorage.emails = JSON.stringify(addresses);
        }

        function foo(){
            var email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
            alert(email);
            storeEmail(email);
        }
</script>
<body>
<input id="Email" name="Email" type="email">
<input type="Submit" id="submit" name="submit" onclick="foo();">
</body>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qb70bedz/)**